# What is the default value for test priority when PriorityAttribute is not set?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

On a TFS build server, I want to run tests that does not have PriorityAttribute set and tests that have priority set to 5. How can I write in "test case filter" that test "does not have priority set"?

I've tried `Priority=0` and `Priority=-1`, but it does not seem to include test without PriorityAttribute.

Comment: You've followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138.aspx#Runner_MSTest), use MSTest runner but tests without priority not run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the output from mstest.exe. It turns out the default value for priority is 2147483647.

Comment: hrmm... that's interesting... so then given that mstest.exe ( 2010 version ) has /minPriority and /maxPriority switches, I guess there's no single invocation that can scoop up undefined and Priority(0) tests?